# How to prove convergence?

Tags: limits

Could somebody help me to solve these two unrelated questions? 
I have to prove or disprove them. The first one is which I have to answer. The second one is just for me, to understand the topic better.

Prove or disprove the following statements:

1. If the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded/restricted then the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ convergent
2. If the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent then the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded/restricted

Comment: You could try to find a counter-example for the first and a proof for the second. Start with the definitions of bounded and convergent.

Comment: actually i dont get it at all. i assume if a seuqence is bounded that it converges on the boundary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

1. If the sequence is bounded, then is it necessarily convergent?
2. If the sequence is convergent, then is it necessarily bounded?

The first statement is false.

Counterexample: Consider the alternating sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$

The second statement is true.

Take $\epsilon=1$.
If the sequence converges to $L$, then there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the $N$th term and beyond are all bounded by an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood. What remains is the first to the $N-1$th term. Take

$M=max(|a_1|,|a_2|,...,|a_{N-1}|,|L|+1)$

and clearly all terms of the sequence are bounded by $M$. Hence the sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** For the first one take the sequence $U_{n}=(-1)^{n}$. This sequence clearly is bounded but does it converge?

For the second one:

Let $(U_n)$ be a convergent sequence, and let $\lim (U_n) = u$. Then taking $\epsilon = 1$ we have:

$n > N \implies |U_n - u| < 1$

From the triangle inequality we see that: $ n > N \implies|U_n| - |u| < 1 \iff |U_n| < |u| + 1$.

Define $M= \max\{|u|+1, |U_1|, |U_2|, ..., |U_N|\}$. Then we have $|U_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in N$.

Comment: we independently thought of the same sequence. Nice.

Comment: ok so its not converging. but if you get -1 1 -1 is it a boundary?

Comment: or what is meant by a boundary? I thougt the limit is the boudary

Comment: @mathemagician Yes we did. That's the sequence I was given as an example when I was dealing with the same problem.

Comment: @Jacky $(-1)^n=1$ if n is even and $-1$ if n is odd so you could say that every bounded sequence has a convergent sub sequence. That is something called the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 0):

1. is false. Counter example $a_n=(-1)^n$ the sequence alternates between 1 and -1 so is bounded, but it is not convergent.
2. is true. If the sequence converges, say to a point $L\in\mathbb{R}^d$ you have that the infinitely many terms of the tail of the sequence are in an epsilon-ball around $L$. Since the first finite terms of the sequence cannot consist of an unbounded set, they are bounded by some ball of radius $M_1$ centered at the origin. You also have that there exists some ball of radius $M_2$ centered at the origin that contains the epsilon-ball containing the tail of the sequence. Hence whichever radius is bigger ($M_1$ or $M_2$) will be a ball that contains all your sequence, therefore sequence is bounded.